# java path on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, cordova, ant

I try to build my app with phonegap. But when I type in command line "phonegap run android"
then I see this error:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: /home/beatnory/ReisWekker/platforms/android/build.xml
```

I think the problem is "ant". When I try to run that I see this

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
```

When I take a look at "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/" I see this folder doesn't exsist.
the good path is "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/".
I added "PATH=${PATH}:~/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/" to the "~/.bash_profile" file.
After I run ant he still use "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Open the build file and see if the path, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/`, is hardcoded in the file. I would expect it use something like `$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`. Also, verify if `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives you the correct path.

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME returned me "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
" I will take a look at the file. thanks